# Javascript setting of select option in Kendo UI MVVM

Tags: javascript, select, mvvm, kendo-ui

I need to use pure JavaScript to select an option from a select element that happens to be bound to a Kendo UI Observable object (MVVM), and I need the bound viewmodel to be updated.

```
<select id="titleField" data-bind="value: Title" >
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
  <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
  <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
</select>
```

I tried:

```
document.getElementById('titleField').value='Mr.';
```

and also:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('titleField');
var opts = sel.options;
for (var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {
  if (opt.value == 'Mr.') {
    sel.selectedIndex = j;
    break;
  }
}
```

They both set the field, however the MVVM binding is not updated.

If the viewmodel is not updated then when the record is saved the selected value is not persisted.

Normally I would manipulate the view model directly and take advantage of two-way binding, something like this:

```
myViewModel.Set("Title", "Mr.");
```

I can't do this however, because I'm running from a CefSharp browser implementation and won't necessarily know or care that Kendo UI is in use.

EDIT: It occurred to me that perhaps the above should work but there was some other weirdness going on, like a timing issue, so I tested it in the website (page loaded javascript) and indeed it does not update the view model using the above techniques.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, so obvious now, must fire the onChange event after updating the element.

For Chrome (my only concern) this works:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
sel.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Now the kendo view model is updated.

Comment: Good question and you just beat me to the same answer so upvoted. As you realised, programmatically updating DOM elements does not fire events as happens when done through the UI.